# Check the kind of unit in Sass/SCSS to optimise CSS

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to check whether the units are compatible and then either use calc() or just calculate them in pre-processing.

Is there any way of checking the unit type in Sass?

If I type:

```
//  SCSS

test {
  content: type-of(1px);
  content: type-of(1%);
  content: type-of(1em);
}
```

I get

```
/*  CSS  */

test  {
  content: number;
  content: number;
  content: number;
}
```

Is there a way of getting something more like:

```
 /*  CSS  */

test {
  content: px;
  content: percent;
  content: em;
}
```

It can potentially save a lot of unnecessary CSS that can be easily optimised in pre-processing.

For example when a @mixin or a @function can take either fixed or flexible units:

```
# flexible container needs calc()
width:calc(((100vw - (12vw + 242px)) / 12) * 6 + 110px)

# fixed main container 
width:calc(((2880px - (110px + 242px)) / 12) * 6 + 110px) 
# can be calculated in SASS and rendered simply as 
width:1374px
```

Comment: What's "ugly" about `margin-left: calc(5px + 5px);`? The spec for CSS doesn't account for any taste in how selectors are constructed.

Comment: @TylerH sure a matter of taste, but the specs aren't everything ;-)

Comment: Sure, but as far as this site is concerned, opinion-based questions are off-topic (I'm just wondering what the motivation is; I haven't voted to close or anything); and ironically, the methods given in the answers below are **way** uglier than the compiled-to-CSS method you posed in your question. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `calc()` is fine, but you could get the units by multiplying the original value by 0, converting to a string, then removing the zero.

```
@function getUnit($value) {
  @return str-slice($value * 0 + "", 2, -1);
}
```

Demo: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6ac692efdbb8a28be8a3cd4346b39970

FYI, there’s also a `unit()` function but the docs warn that:

> “This function is intended for debugging; its output format is not
>   guaranteed to be consistent across Sass versions or implementations.”

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#unit

If that’s not a concern for your use case, then that would probably be the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own functions that returns either `true` or `false` based on the unit you are checking for.

Kitty Giraudel wrote about [advanced type checking](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/advanced-type-checking/) in Sass some years ago, and made some useful snippets you could possibly re-use.

For example you can check if the value is a number with an `em` or `px` unit like this (remove one of them from `index()` if you want to check for a single unit):

```scss
@function is-em($value) {
  @return is-number($value) and index('em', 'px', unit($value)) != null;
}

@debug is-em(42em); // true
@debug is-em(42px); // true
@debug is-em(42vw); // false
```

Or if the value is a number with a `%` unit like this:

```scss
@function is-percentage($value) {
  @return is-number($value) and unit($value) == "%";
}

@debug is-percentage(42.1337%); // true
@debug is-percentage(42cm);     // false
```

Perhaps not as simple as the test examples in your question, but the only way I can think of to check for numbers and units like this.